# Dependent Care FSA Payment - Bill Before End of Plan, Due Date After Plan Year Ends

Tags: united-states, fsa, dependents, child-care

My Dependent Care FSA plan year ends on 3/31/21. The plan says the last day to incur expenses is 3/31/21 and the last day to submit requests is 6/30/21. If I get a bill sent to me before 3/31/21 with a due date after 3/31/21 for day care, can I use my Dependent Care FSA funds from the current year's plan (4/1/20-3/31/21) to pay for child care expenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the due date. What matters is the date of service / when services were incurred.

Note: One thing to watch for. My FSA plan is 1/1/2020 - 12/31/2020 but I can use the FSA account balance to pay for expenses up through March. If that is the case for you, make sure you identify that the claim should use the 2020 FSA account, not the 2021 account. I had that happen one year. Luckily, I had enough other expenses that I could still clear out the previous year's account.